# Adding a label inside a promptbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, prompt

I want to get the password from the user by means of a prompt box and if the entered password is invalid show an error message in a label which is inside the promptbox I mentioned.I s it possible or not?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to accept answers if you got your answer. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lots of controls available for doing thing such this:

[jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

[Kendo UI](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html)

[Bootstrapper](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

And so on,Hope this help.

Comment: Your-welcome, as I know your are Persian, I suggest you to use jQuery and KendoUI because Bootstrapper doesn't support RTL languages.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do so as it is controlled by browser.

insted you can use other dialog boxes eg

jQuery UI Dialog

colorbox

thinkbox etc

Comment: u r most welcome brother. nice to meet a developer form iran as i am a fan of Mr. Ahmadinejad :)

Comment: @Zia It's not a brother, It's a sister. :D